# Enable Auto Completion in MongoChef

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and am using MongoChef as the GUI. The auto completion or intellisense is not enabled in Chef.

I was unable to find anything on their official websites either. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "autocompletion"? There really isn't much available other than what is possible in the plain mongo shell ( which the GUI basically wraps the same library from ) which is to expose the available JavaScript prototype methods on valid objects.

Comment: In the youtube videos that I have seen, the shell shows Intellisense when typing various key words. I was wondering if the current version of MongoChef has the intellisense

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. any solution found?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue.